# Annual Town Hall Meeting!

Tags: discussion, participation, chat, town-hall

In June 2020 I made the suggestion for us to have weekly town hall meetings, a bit like Quantum Computing SE has "The Quantum Revolution" every Tuesday and Meta.SE has "Happy Hour" every Thursday: [What time of the week would people like to hold town hall meetings (if any such thing at all)?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/127/5)

That was only about a fortnight after this site entered Public Beta, so it might have been too ambitious a suggestion because:

- We didn't actually have a lot of users (not nearly as many as we have now)
- People were exhausted from the grueling hours we put into getting through the Commitment Phase and then Private Beta.

**However, I think it's now high time that we organize a chat session where we give the entire community an opportunity to give feedback and actually discuss how we feel about things *in realtime*.**

Does anyone have objections to doing this on 19 May 2021 (UST) which is exactly 1 year after we entered Public Beta? Or would a weekday be better?

Please provide feedback here on:

- When you would be available
- What topics you'd like to discuss!

Comment: I'm not opposed, but I don't know how active it would be. I don't use the SE chat system  much.

Comment: A crazy idea, what if we organized a virtual poster session to get to know each other. I've found the gather town platform to be a lot of fun. We could talk about research and other things. I don't really know what else we could talk about that isn't already addressed in the chat rooms and other channels.

Comment: @CodyAldaz that's a brilliant idea!